# grails domain class multiple circular reference issue

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Having a case where a domain has been a property of itself as below:

```
Group{
    String name
    Role role
    static belongsTo=[boss:Group]
    static hasMany=[children:Group,supporters:Group]
}

static constraint={
     boss nullable:true
     supporters validator: {supporters, group->
            supporters?.each {Group supplier ->
                if(!(supporters.role == Role.OPS)){
                    return "domain.not.supporters.object"
                }
            }
            return true
        }
}
}

Role{
   MANAGER,LEADER,DEVELOPERS,OPS
}
```

Above supporters are with role OPS for which we have added validation as well. Overall supporters don't come under original `Manager>Leader>Developer hierarchy`.

Now, when I create few objects of children groups say `MANAGER_RAD > LEAD_BAD ->( DEV_JACK and DEV_MOHAN)` and supporters are only provided to Managers. Code below will make understand the scenario:

```
Group manager = new Group(name:'MANAGER_RAD')
manager.addToSupporters(new Group(name:'OPS_BISK').save(flush:true))
manager.addToSupporters(new Group(name:'OPS_BAHADUR').save(flush:true))
Group lead = new Group(name:'LEAD_BAD').save(flush:true)
lead.addToChildren(new Group(name:'DEV_JACK').save(flush:true))
lead.addToChildren(new Group(name:'DEV_MOHAN').save(flush:true))
lead.save(flush:true)
manager.addToChildren(lead)
manager.save()
```

Now, when we try to get children of manager as follows(say in our bootstrap):

```
Group manager = Group.findByName('MANAGER_RAD')
println "------Manager team members---->$manager.children"
println "------supporters for Manager---->$manager.supporters"
```

The expected output is:

```
------Manager team members---->[LEAD_BAD(id:2)]
------supporters for Manager---->[OPS_BAHADUR(id:7),OPS_BISK(id:7)]
```

But the output returned is:

```
------Manager team members---->[LEAD_BAD(id:2),OPS_BAHADUR(id:7),OPS_BISK(id:7)]
------supporters for Manager---->[LEAD_BAD(id:2),OPS_BAHADUR(id:7),OPS_BISK(id:7)]
```

How can I get the expected output.

Any help would be worth.

Comment: You maybe missing the `mappedBy` property. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html.

Comment: I tried with mappedBy as well, but in vain.

Comment: Good to see I was right (guessing by you accepting the answer suggesting the use of the `mappedBy` property) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code have self referential property(**boss**) and also two different association properties of same type, Grails is not able to create the proper schema.

From Grails docs:

> Occasionally you may find yourself with domain classes that have
>   multiple properties of the same type. They may even be
>   self-referential, i.e. the association property has the same type as
>   the domain class it's in. Such situations can cause problems because
>   Grails may guess incorrectly the type of the association.

In your case Grails is generating a single table and your children and supporters properties are being bind to **boss_id** column in schema.

To overcome this situation you can use **mappedBy** and specify the property names for children and supporters property to be bind to the property names.

After changes your domain class will look like this:

```
class Group {
    String name
    Role role

    static belongsTo = [boss: Group]
    static hasMany = [children: Group, supporters: Group]

    static mapping = {
        table 'groups'
    }

    static mappedBy = [children  : "none",
                       supporters: "none"]

    static constraints = {
        boss nullable: true
        role nullable: true
        supporters validator: { supporters, group ->
            supporters?.each { Group supplier ->
                if (supporters.role != Role.OPS) {
                    return "domain.not.supporters.object"
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }

}

enum Role {
    MANAGER, LEADER, DEVELOPERS, OPS
}
```

Now Grails will generate two tables for you: **groups and groups_groups**.
If you will skip **mappedBy** for either of the property, that property will bind to '**boss_id**' column in **groups** table.

Structure of **groups_groups** table would be:

```
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
| group_children_id | group_id | group_supporters_id |
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

refer to https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#domainClasses for more explanation.